# Take Average in sql stored procedure multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table as below :

```
Age Gender Shoesize
1   Male    121
2   Female  130
2   Female  138
2   m   147
2   Male    130
2   Male    138
3   Female  130
3   Female  138
3   Female  147
3   Female  155
3   Female  164
3   Female  172
3   Male    130
3   Male    138
3   Male    147
3   Male    155
3   Male    164
3   Male    172
3   Male    181
3   Male    189
4   f   147
4   f   155
4   f   164
4   f   172
4   f   181
4   F   281
4   Female  138
4   Female  147
4   Female  155
4   Female  164
4   Female  172
4   Female  181
4   Female  189
4   Female  197
4   m   130
4   m   147
4   m   155
4   m   164
4   m   172
4   m   181
4   Male    121
4   Male    147
4   Male    155
4   Male    164
4   Male    172
```

I want to display for example for all the Age= 1 , The average shoe size for the Males for that particular shoe size same in case of females.

```
       Males          Females
Age  ShoeSize(Avg)  ShoeSize(Avg)
```

Please help i am new to `SQL`

```
    Select Age, ChildGender, Shoesize, AVG(Shoesize) from [dbo].[Transaction]

GROUP BY Age , ChildGender, Shoesize
```

**EDIT:**

Have made this how do i combine these two queries

```
 Select AVG(Shoesize) AS AverageShoeSizeMale, Age from [dbo].[Transaction] where ChildGender = 'm' or ChildGender = 'male' Group by Age ORDER BY Age DESC



 Select AVG(Shoesize) AS AverageShoeSizeFemale, Age from [dbo].[Transaction] where ChildGender = 'f' or ChildGender = 'female' Group by Age ORDER BY Age DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you task can be the following:

```
select age,
       (select avg(ShoeSize) from [table] t2 where t2.age = t1.age and t2.Gender='Male') as avg_male,
       (select avg(ShoeSize) from [table] t2 where t2.age = t1.age and t2.Gender='Female') as avg_female
from [table] t1
group by ide
```

However, I wouldn't recomment to use subqueries. I'm not sure whether it is possible to avoid them in such kind of task.

Better way is to get data and utilize them from the plain table:

```
select age, Gender, AVG(ShoeSize)
from [table]
group by age, Gender
order by age
```

Comment: Hi Thanks so much how do i take the average of the avg_male and avg_female columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "take average of avg_male and avg_female"? They already contain average data grouped by age and gender. By the way, I think that sureshhh's answer is much better than mine :)

Comment: Hi i also want to take the average of the two columns and display it in the third column like = avg_total

Comment: Just add another subquery before the "from.." line: (select avg(ShoeSize) from [table] t2 where t2.id = t1.id) as avg_all.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS..

```
SELECT AGE , MALE,FEMALE,,(MALE+FEMALE)/CAST(2 AS DECIMAL(5,3)) [AVG]
 from [dbo].[Transaction] PIVOT ( AVG(Shoesize ) FOR GENDER IN (male,female)) AS PVT
ORDER BY AGE
```